# Tableau Username() function to filter Revenue data by SalesRep

Tags: tableau-api

How do I filter the Sales Revenue by SalesRep so that each SalesRep should be able to see only the sales volume generated by them using the username() function.

Let's assume John generated $2000 revenue, Jena generated $3000 and Eric generated $5000. Total sales volume combined for all 3 SalesRep is $10000. Employee ID of John is 101, Eric is 102, Jena is 103. I'm the manager and my employee ID is 104. I want to use the username() function in Tableau to filter the data in a such a way that John should see only revenue generated by him i.e. $2000 and he should be able to see the revenue generated by Jena in the bar chart. Similarly, Eric and Jena should be able to check their respective sales revenue. However, I should have the access to the revenue of all 3 as I'm their manager. How do I implement it in Tableau using the USERNAME() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**One possible solution could be with the help of `ISUSERNAME()`:**

Let's say `SalesRep` is an existing dimension in the datasource which has sales representative's full name or username or empid (Note: In below illustration I am considering that it has username e.g. John, Eric etc. For other options refer [here](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/functions_functions_user.html)).

- Create a calculated field `SalesUsersList` as below (here list down ALL
  members entry):

---

```
IF ISUSERNAME("John_Tableu_Username") THEN "John" 
ELSEIF ISUSERNAME("Eric_Tableu_Username") THEN "Eric" 
ELSEIF ISUSERNAME("Jena_Tableu_Username") THEN "Jena" 
ELSEIF ISUSERNAME("Manager_Tableu_Username") THEN "Manager_Username" 
END
```

- Create a calculated field `LimitedAccessUsers` as below (here list
  down ALL sales team's members entry who will have limited access):

---

```
([SalesUsersList]="John") or ([SalesUsersList]="Eric") or ([SalesUsersList]="Jena")
```

- Create a calculated field `hasLimitedAccess` as below. Drag it to
  'Filters' section and select `True`

---

```
NOT[LimitedAccessUsers] OR ([SalesUsersList]=[SalesRep])
```

*Don't forget to let us know in case it solved your problem :)*

Comment: @Amit if you liked the solution then you should vote up/ accept it as the right answer. It'll surely help others in case they encounter similar problem in future. Thanks!

Comment: I solved it by using a different approach. Though, this seems to be a good solution too. I'm not facing another issue. I want the salesrep to see both theirs and OVERALL TEAMS PERFORMANCE. Is it possible to create a TOGGLE SWITCH : ME/TEAM...when they click on ME - it shows them their revenue and when they click on TEAM - it show overall team revenue. But, they still shouldn't be able to see other salesman revenue...Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's very much possible. You just need to create another sheet 'Team_Performance' for overall team performance and then just follow this [link](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/help.htm#dashboards_sheet_selector.html) to create toggle behavior between 'me' & 'Team_Performance' sheet on your dashboard.